# How to pretty print clean TypeScript errors in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, error-handling

I find the inline error popup in VS Code difficult to read. There are no line breaks and there is no syntax highlighting to make the structure of a type in the diagnostic message easier to understand. Is there a way to get either of those things?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very promising solution, released a week ago:

[TypeScript Error Translator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mattpocock.ts-error-translator)

[image: ts-error-translator]

GitHub: https://github.com/mattpocock/ts-error-translator

Comment: While this extension can be useful, it does not solve this particular issue.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, it is not supported.

Read more about it here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/54272